# Python - Undo script if script fails

Tags: python, undo

Sometimes when I run a function in my python script and if the function gives me an output which is not desired, I need to undo this step and then try running the function again with different parameters. Is there a way that I can have the script undo what it has done if my function gives me a wrong output.For only one set of parameters, the desired output is acheived.

PS: By running the function means making permanent changes.

Example:

```
def function():
    for i in range(parameters):
        value = perform_operation(parameters[i]) #makes permanent changes 
        if value != some_value:
            undo(perform_operation())
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such a function? If you are consistently (or often enough) getting wrong output then the function might be wrong. If that is not the case, simply check the correctness of your output with an `if` like so: `if not correct_output: your_function(new_input)`. Give an example of the output too, depending on what your output looks like undo-ing it is very different.

Comment: What do you mean by "undo what it has done"? Maybe you can do it by a `try` - `except` clause, raising an exception inside `try` and undo the changes on `except`

Comment: Just use a conditional statement? `if something: value = perform_operation() elif something_else: value = whatevs ...`

Comment: Why don't you make changes on a copy and make them permanent if conditions are met?

Comment: @MrGrj  I need to call perform_operation() initially, based on its return value I need to decide if this operation is satisfied or not. Because perform_operation() makes permanent changes I need to be more careful.

Comment: There's nothing that does this automatically. If you need to undo things, your script needs to save the old values somewhere so it can put them back.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another function than cleans what was done in the main function for example (delete newly created files, remove installed packages, etc ...) and use it.

```
def main_func():
    proc = subprocess.Popen('touch test test2')
    return proc.returncode

def clean_main_func():
   subprocess.Popen('rm test test2')


def __name__ == '__main__':
    result = main_func()
    if main_func() != 0 :
       clean_main_func()
```

or you can raise an error then catch it:

```
def main_func():
    proc = subprocess.Popen('touch test test2')
    if proc.returncode !=0 :
       raise Error

def clean_main_func():
   subprocess.Popen('rm test test2')


def __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        result = main_func()
    except Error:
        clean_main_func()
```

It's juste an example , and hope it answer your question.

Comment: This worked great for me and helped me rethink my design. Just one comment, I think @silmtabka did not mean to create a `__name__` function, but an if statement. e.g. `if __name__ == '__main__':`